# how to organize tableview cells

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uitableview

I have two different kinds of tableview cells in one table view. The first cell prints out original comments to a post, the second cell prints out comments to another comment. Currently, the tableview prints out all the correct cells in no particular order. However, I want to print the cells in a particular order. I want the cells that contain comments to another comment to appear below the comment it is being commented on.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure the cell...

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Main", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

        //Configure the cell

        cell.PostView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.PostView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.PostView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
        cell.PostView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        cell.PostView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9

        let post = Comments[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let commentname = post["author"] as? String
        sendAuthor = post["author"] as? String
        cell.CommentersName.setTitle(commentname, for: .normal)

        if let seconds = post["pub_time"] as? Double {
            let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds/1000)
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
            let formating = timeStampDate as Date


            cell.CommentTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: formating)


        }

        cell.comment.text = post["content"] as? String


         textViewDidChange(cell.comment)

        cell.comment.frame.size.width = 344
        cell.comment.sizeToFit()
        cell.comment.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.REply.frame.origin.y = cell.comment.frame.maxY + 10
        cell.report.frame.origin.y = cell.comment.frame.maxY + 10
        cell.Likes.frame.origin.y = cell.comment.frame.maxY + 10
        cell.LikesNumber.frame.origin.y = cell.comment.frame.maxY + 10
        cell.PostView.frame.size.height =  cell.comment.frame.maxY + 50
        TableView.rowHeight = cell.PostView.frame.size.height + 20

        cell.CommentersName.sizeToFit()

        cell.pole.frame.origin.x = cell.CommentersName.frame.maxX + 5
        cell.CommentTime.frame.origin.x = cell.pole.frame.maxX + 5

        let numLikes = post["num_likes"] as?  NSNumber
        cell.LikesNumber.text = String(describing: numLikes!)



        replyId = post["id"] as? String

        let replyTo = post["reply_to"] as? String
        let postID = post["post_id"] as? String



        if replyTo == postID {

        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reply", for: indexPath) as! RepliesTableViewCell



            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9

            let post = Comments[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]

            cell.ReplyText.text = post["content"] as? String
            let commentname = post["author"] as? String
            cell.author.setTitle(commentname, for: .normal)

            if let seconds = post["pub_time"] as? Double {
                let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds/1000)
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
                let formating = timeStampDate as Date


                cell.time.text = dateFormatter.string(from: formating)


            }

            let numLikes = post["num_likes"] as?  NSNumber
            cell.num_likes.text = String(describing: numLikes!)


            textViewDidChange(cell.ReplyText)

            cell.ReplyText.frame.size.width = 232
            cell.ReplyText.sizeToFit()
            cell.ReplyText.clipsToBounds = true

            cell.author.sizeToFit()

            cell.pole.frame.origin.x = cell.author.frame.maxX + 5
            cell.time.frame.origin.x = cell.pole.frame.maxX + 5

            cell.Likes.frame.origin.y = cell.ReplyText.frame.maxY + 10
            cell.num_likes.frame.origin.y = cell.ReplyText.frame.maxY + 10
            cell.reportButton.frame.origin.y = cell.ReplyText.frame.maxY + 10
            cell.replyButton.frame.origin.y = cell.ReplyText.frame.maxY + 10
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.frame.size.height =  cell.ReplyText.frame.maxY + 50

             TableView.rowHeight = cell.ReplyCustomCell.frame.size.height + 20

            return cell
        }

        cell.checkfornightmode()

        return cell

    }
```

The comments that are associated with each other have the same "id", how will I organize the cells so that the comments of a main comment will be listed under the original comment. Thank you

Comment: You need to sort your `Comments` Array. Also, don't name your var starting with an uppercase.

Comment: @Larme how will I sort it ? Can you please give me an example

Comment: @Larme like I said comments associated with each other have the same ID in firebase, will I sort it by That?

Answer (score 1):

You can create one Comment custom object class which will hold an array of sub comments and the main comment to arrange or manage your data structure properly. After that you can use it properly with your table view cell.
Okay so for example you can have the below data structure.

Create one Comment class:

```
class Comment {
comment_id
content
post_id
reply_to
}
```

Now create one more class for your table view:

```
class CommentTableDataModel {
var mainComment: Comment // Of type Comment class
var replies: [Comment] // Array of type Comment class for sub comments
}
```

So now just iterate through your firebase Comments array and prepare an array list of type 'CommentTableDataModel' objects as a datasource for your table. So finally you will have an array of type object 'CommentTableDataModel' and each object of type 'CommentTableDataModel' contains the main comment info as well as the list of replies info with that, with this you can manage your data.

Comment: can you please give an example, how will I organize two arrays in one object class

Comment: can u tell me more about the data structure u have ? how u find comment and its sub-comments ? and what is replyId = post["id"] as? String,
let replyTo = post["reply_to"] as? String and let postID = post["post_id"] as? String ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372955/organize-tableview-cell-by-firebase-child

Comment: The link I just posted is basically asking the same question and I gave a more in-depth description of my code.

Comment: Please check my ans. now I have edited, I have added one example to explain it.

Comment: is there a way I can reach you personally so that you could take a look at my code. I am still an amateur and I am having a really hard time implementing this

Comment: You can mail me at vivek39ster@gmail.com

Comment: I sent you an email. Thank you!

Comment: i sent you another email, I am not sure you received it

Comment: Okay I will check bro.